# Is this the correct way to do Dependency Injection in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, vows, sinon

I recently started a node project and as a Test-Driven Developer, I quickly ran into a dependency injection problem with my brand new module.
Here's how I figured out I should do dependency injection. It's important to note I'm using [vows](http://vowsjs.org/) as BDD framework and extend it with [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/).

My module:

```
exports.myMethod = function () {
  var crypto = exports.cryptoLib || require('ezcrypto').Crypto;
  crypto.HMAC(
    crypto.SHA256,
    'I want to encrypt this',
    'with this very tasty salt'
  );
};
```

My test:

```
var vows = require('vows'),
  sinon = require('sinon');

vows.describe('myObject').addBatch({
  'myMethod':{
    'topic':true,
    'calls ezcrypto.HMAC':function () {
      var myObject = require('../playground.js');
      var mock = sinon.mock(require('ezcrypto').Crypto);

      myObject.cryptoLib = mock;
      myObject.cryptoLib.HMAC = mock.expects("HMAC").once().withExactArgs(
        require('ezcrypto').Crypto.SHA256,
        'I want to encrypt this',
        'with this very tasty salt'
      );
      myObject.cryptoLib.SHA256 = require('ezcrypto').Crypto.SHA256;
      myObject.cryptoLib = mock;
      myObject.myMethod();
      mock.verify();
    }
  }
}).export(module);
```

Do you think this the correct way to go? I like this solution because it doesn't require more when you use the module (like adding "()" after the require statement).

Comment: You have not said what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure this is the correct way to go. Looking for a validation I'm not doing something fundamentally flawed here.

Comment: At least the test passes. It's more about code design that I'm wondering if it's kosher.

Comment: Nothing is true, everything is permitted.

Answer (score 3):

It's not good way to trash your code with test stuff. Line 2 of your code

```
var crypto = exports.cryptoLib || require('ezcrypto').Crypto;
```

Looks like unnecesary interface. I suggest you to replace it with

```
var crypto = require('ezcrypto').Crypto;
```

Much cleaner. And in test just mock Crypto method of 'ezcrypto' module. Just do not forget to revert it back after using.

Comment: Can you show me I should mock Crypto and inject the mock in my module during the test please?

Comment: It's dead-simple:
`var oldCrypto = require('ezcrypto').Crypto;
require('ezcrypto').Crypto = MyCrypto; // mock
// do tests`

Comment: `require()` guarantees that it returned a memorized result, which is what enables this

Comment: I still have mixed feelings about this. Not that it wouldn't work but using the global domain to inject dependencies (not only for test BTW)  makes me uncomfortable. Especially knowing that test suites run tests asynchronously. I wonder if there is not a chance other tests would get screwed by the globally overridden object.

Comment: I think running tests in parallel is not good idea. But when running sequentially there's no problem to override whole module. It even better than trash your code with test-only interfaces.

Comment: TDD is all about test independence. Please read Kent Beck TDD by example. It's very important to have independent tests. That's why test frameworks don't bother running tests sequentially. I'm not even sure you can configure Vows or Jasmine to run tests sequentially.